# When Installing nvidia drivers it doesnt resuming suspend

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, suspend, power-management

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I installed recommended Nvidia drivers from "Additional Drivers." Now when I try to resume from suspend the monitor doesn't show anything and I have to restart my computer.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: can you provide some more info about your computer? model, graphic card, etc.. I know there was a known issue with system76 laptops and long wake up times from suspend in 11.04 and 11.10. Not sure if that is the case here though

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have: core2duo proccessor, and nvidia GeForce 430 graphic card ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't resume after install nvidia drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147330/ubuntu-12-04-doesnt-resume-after-install-nvidia-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

nvidia drivers in 12.04 provide many stability problems (resume/suspend)... look on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/1033263

its good to consider switching from propetriary nvidia driver to nouveau